# Insurance statistics book

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, risk-assessment

Am am looking for a book on insurance statistics.

The problem is that there are a lot of googleable variants that it is difficult to decide which one is good and which ones are better in good ones. This is why I am asking here for sugestion.

To be short I am looking for a good reference which, if it is possible, describes mathematical tools for borh life insurance and non-life insurance.

It would be great if the reference was about statistics and about the liability side of the balance sheet as well as about finance and the asset side of the balance sheet.

My math background is intermediate but if the level needed for a prospective reference is indicated, references for various math background will be appreciated.

EDIT(27.08): I am not going to pass any exam to work in insurance.
I am asking for text book on mathematical techniques in insurance. And I am expecting for references based on personal preferences for writing style, approach.

Comment: You might find a book aimed at actuarial science meets your needs

Comment: I am sorry, @Henry what exacly do you mean, and what do you sugest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not useful to give specific recommendations here because we do not know the country in which you may eventually seek work as an actuary. Also, just based on personal preferences for writing style, approach, and level each of us might give
different answers. However, there may be a strategy
for getting unbiased and authoritative advice; in particular, the following should work in the US and Canada.

Eventually, I suppose you will take several actuarial exams prepared by actuarial societies or regulatory agencies in your country. Look at the web sites that discuss the exams and how to prepare for them. Often there are lists of textbooks with cross references to exam topics and sessions. Choose from among those textbooks.

Comment: Thank you for a response, I will surely try to search for a exam based references, though I am not going to work in insurance and as a result I am not going to pass any exams on it. I am looking for just a book about math techniques in insurance.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at math stat books co-authored by R. Hogg which have been written and used for students in an actuarial program at the authors' university.

Comment: Thank you once more, Hogg's book looks a good book on general mathematical statistics and but it seems to me that it is aimed for beginners in mathematical statistics. I rather prefer also to look at some advanced mathematical techniques in insurance.

Comment: Don't know which Hogg book you've looked at. There are several with different co-authors. Even so you may be looking for something more like [Casella-Berger](https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Inference-George-Casella/dp/05342431260).

Comment: I have looked first at 'Intro to math statistics' and after that one to 'Loss distributions'.